# Is it possible to make realistic animations in 2D?

Tags: 2d, animation

I plan to make a skateboarding game and I am wondering about one thing: is it possible to make 2D realistic animations to simulate skate's and skater's rotations or should I resort to 3D for realistic visual effects?

P.S: As you guess I am new to game development.

Comment: It is certainly possible to make realistic 2D animations, you just need to have the right skills, or the money to hire someone to do it, and the hardware to support it. There have been realistic 2D games in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If realism is really a concern for you, 3D animations will work the best. We live in a 3D world after all. Note that you can have 3D modelling & animation, but keep the gameplay in 2D. For instance, check Trials: https://youtu.be/mhsusQvTab8?t=2m23s.

On the other hand 2D animation can look great if done properly, even if it's *not* realistic. Check Rayman Origins for instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syNWMkBSmLU. It's also simpler to implement & author.

But since you're a beginner, I suggest you start small and prototype some basic gameplay without even thinking about animation. You'll see how this goes: animation is tightly coupled with gameplay, so it's probably something to figure out after you have a first playable prototype.